# Why is my function being imported as the value '0' in ES6?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm working in react.js with redux and ES6.  I have an actions file exporting a function like so:

```
MonthlyRevenueActions.js

export function fetchMonthlyRevenue(name, startDate, endDate) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(console.log("name": " + name + ", start: " + startDate + ", end: " + endDate));
    }
}
```

Then in my container code, I have an import statement and try to use the function, but I can see in Chrome DevTools that the variable's value is 0:

```
MonthlyDisplayContainer.js:
import {otherFunc, fetchMonthlyRevenue, otherFunctionTwo} from 'actions/monthly/MonthlyRevenueActions'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

    //...  other code that's being executed

    fetchMonthlyRevenue(name, startDate, endDate);
}
```

[image: Chrome DevTools snapshot]

I can see values for `name`, `startDate`, and `endDate`, but the `fetchMonthlyRevenue()` function is just 0.

I expect I'm missing something when it comes to scope (I'm new to ES6), but for the life of me can't figure out how to execute this function.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't understand that line of code. You're executing a function, that returns a function, and doing nothing with the return value? yeah the 0 is weird, but... so is the code..

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It's not giving an error... it's the code runs through, giving no error at all.  If i put a `console.log()` in it prints out alongside the `fetchMonthlyRevenue()` line.

Comment: So... while not giving an explicit 'error' per-se, I'm clearly trying to import / use the function wrongly... but I'm confused why that would be happening.  At the bottom of this file (outside the `mapToProps()` function, the `fetchMonthlyRevenue()` method executes properly)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is probably picking up the transpiled source of your import. Are you using sourcemaps? Perhaps they are not being created or loaded properly.

Babel does the following to imports...

**In...**

```
import { a } from 'a'
a()
```

**Out...**

```
'use strict';

var _a = require('a');

(0, _a.a)();
```

[Check it out on the Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=import%20%7B%20a%20%7D%20from%20'a'%0A%0Aa()%0A).

(This changes depending on the type of import, e.g. default, named.)

Notice how the function call of the imported value is changed on the last line:

```
(0, _a.a)();
```

Comment: Yes, we're using sourcemaps.  I think the source is being loaded correctly in chrome... I can see the values for other variables in the same code block... and within this same file, just in a different function... I can execute the function I'm importing.  My suspicion is it's something to do with scope depending on when the method is being executed... but I cannot understand why

Comment: @Cuga The other variables presumably are not imports from another module? Which would be why you are not seeing the same behaviour for them as you are with the imported function.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  All the other imports are working in the file as far as I know... as well this exact import used in just another method in the same file.  I'm half-curious if it has to do with whether this import exists at the time it's executing `mapStateToProps` in redux.... if that makes any sense.

Comment: What if you log ``fetchMonthlyRevenue`` to the console (this avoids any issues with sourcemaps chrome may or may not have during debugging), is the value still ``0``?

Comment: Any luck with figuring this out? I just ran into this issue - I've imported several functions from a file and one is "0". The others work however.